# Why I can't fetch data properly with proxy?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I want to fetch data from an API for my weather app. 
Here is my code example:

```
if(navigator.geolocation){
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position =>{
    long = position.coords.longitude;  
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    const proxy = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
    const api = 
    '${proxy}https://api.darksky.net/forecast/4f94f918cc790acff94560f7961cc71f/${lat},${long}';
    fetch(api)
    .then(response =>{
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data =>{
      console.log(data)
      const {temperature, summary} = data.currently;
      temperatureDegree.textContent = temperature
    });
  });
}
```

And it doesn't fetch. I don't really know what's going on. Weather API from Darksky.

Comment: You should use another parentheses for combining string and variables. Replace ' ' with ` `

Comment: @SergeyGubarev your right, but also wrong, `` is known as [template-literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and sure not a pair of parentheses! You can use words such as; `back-ticks` or `grave accent `

Comment: @DanStarns thank you for your remark, nice to know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wanting to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

You need to use backticks instead of `'`.

This line needs to be:

```
const api = `${proxy}https://api.darksky.net/forecast/4f94f918cc790acff94560f7961cc71f/${lat},${long}`;
```

Comment: it won't happen again 